# How to add placeholder with dynamic options in ckeditor

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, placeholder

I am using the ckeditor plugin and i need to replace the content with dynamic loaded options using placeholder, i have `config.extraPlugins = 'placeholder';` in **config.js** and **ckeditor/plugins/placeholder/plugin.js** as follows:

```
'use strict';

CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'placeholder', function( editor ) {
    var lang = editor.lang.placeholder,
        generalLabel = editor.lang.common.generalTab,
        validNameRegex = /^[^\[\]<>]+$/;

    return {
        title: lang.title,
        minWidth: 300,
        minHeight: 80,
        contents: [
            {
                id: 'info',
                label: generalLabel,
                title: generalLabel,
                elements: [
                    // Dialog window UI elements.
                    {
                        id: 'name',
                        type: 'text',
                        style: 'width: 100%;',
                        label: lang.name,
                        'default': '',
                        required: true,
                        validate: CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.regex( validNameRegex, lang.invalidName ),
                        setup: function( widget ) {
                            this.setValue( widget.data.name );
                        },
                        commit: function( widget ) {
                            widget.setData( 'name', this.getValue() );
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this post that helped me atleast add static elements to a placeholder of type "Dropdown", Not sure if [enter link description here][1]

https://zolson.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/ckeditor-placeholder-select/